# Error: Could not find or load main class ’-Xmx1G’

Tags: java, gradle

I have Reinstalled both gradle and java but when I run any gradle command get this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ’-Xmx1G’
```

I have tried reading up about it but nothing i tried seemed to solve it

How I installed Java: apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer

How I installed Gradle: apt-get install -y gradle

Comment: looks like some missing environment variable. Please follow the install guide again

Comment: You have a config error. You're going to need to include some more information. How you are trying to run gradle. -Xmx1G is an option to the JVM to limit the amount of memory to be used. It is really strange the option is being interpreted as the name of the main class.

Comment: So i was using gradle for mostly building projects i work on in intellij , Gradle was working normally about a week ago but then when i ran a build then i started gettting this error.
When I installed gradle i was told to just make sure the JAVA_HOME env was set and i did so.

Comment: The java8-installer only installs the installer. Have you tried just typing gradle (or whatever the command is) into the terminal?